# Why onHorizontalDragUpdate calls multiples in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
                    int sensitivity = 8;
                    if (details.primaryVelocity > sensitivity) {
                      myFunction1();
                    } else if (details.primaryVelocity < -sensitivity) {
                      myFunction2();
                    }
                  }
```

I thought that myFunction will call only one time in one scroll, but it calls it multiple times.

Is there any better way to detect the horizontal scroll?

Comment: Sorry. It means onHorizontalDragUpdate. I updated my code.

Comment: ok, you can use `onHorizontalDragEnd` - it has velocity info so you can detect if its was right or left swipe

Comment: Oh, I tried that but it works sometime but it doesn't works sometime.

Comment: eee, it should work just fine - you need to be sure that you release your finger though.... - it is not called when you just stop moving your finger

Comment: Even in sometime, I swipe to right but it works left swipe function.

Comment: post your code with `onHorizontalDragEnd` then...

Comment: you can see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cc9b78fc5c/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/dismissible.dart#L465) how `Dismissible` handles drag end

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onHorizontalDragUpdate.html) says:
"A pointer that is in contact with the screen with a primary button and moving horizontally has moved in the horizontal direction."

This is the behavior expected by the component, it will call the function whenever it sees that the OffSet has changed, you can try "onHorizontalDragEnd" which will only call the function when the touch leaves the screen, or even create a sensitivity control mechanism for the " onHorizontalDragEnd" won't be called that often.

```
onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) async {
        if (controller.chartScrollSensitive == 10) {
          if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
            myFunction1();
          } else if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
            myFunction2();
          }
          controller.chartScrollSensitive = 0;
        } else {
          controller.chartScrollSensitive++;
        }
      },
```

You can create the "chartScrollSensitive" variable in a controller on your page (recommended) or even directly on your page.